# Have ADFS authenticate against ASP.NET Membership database

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, single-sign-on, adfs

Is it possible to make make ADFS to authenticate a user against an ASP.NET Membership database in SQL Server? Alternatively can a .NET C# plug-in be created and installed in ADFS which could provide this "service" to ADFS?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible. ADFS (v1 and v2) ONLY supports an AD Domain Controller as the Authentication source of users. Other flavors of AD do not work (ADAM/AD LDS).

There are other options that are easier to deploy and give you IP-STS (aka IDP) functionality. For example, our [PingFederate](http://www.pingidentity.com/our-solutions/pingfederate.cfm) product can leverage your SQL Server pretty easily if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.  See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313512/can-i-use-adfs-2-0-to-authenticate-certain-users-against-sql-server/4938662#4938662) for the official documentation at this point, and for an alternative solution involving a custom STS.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of issues with ADFS can be worked around by federating ADFS with another STS and adding the required functionality to the STS.

[StarterSTS](http://startersts.codeplex.com/) is a good example of an STS that authenticates against an instance of a SQL Server aspnetdb database.