# Custom username/password validator

Tags: adfs2.0

Is it possible to write a custom username/password validator which will be used in the adfs signin method (on the formssignin.aspx page)?

And if so, are there any examples?

Answer (score 3):

This article [customizing-the-ad-fs-2-0-sign-in-web-pages](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/steve/archive/2011/02/27/tweaking-the-default-adfs-v2-web-experience.aspx) shows how to add two factor authentication.

This article [modifying-and-securing-the-adfs-2-web-application](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/steve/archive/2010/09/13/modifying-and-securing-the-adfs-2-web-application.aspx) shows how to create a VS project from the ADFS files on your dev. PC.

ADFS has a Master page and css files as well depending on how far you want to go.

Also, there's some info. here [customizing-the-ad-fs-2-0-sign-in-web-pages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2010/01/27/customizing-the-ad-fs-2-0-sign-in-web-pages.aspx) about other changes you may care to make e.g.

- Customizing the Sign-In Pages Using Web.config
- ASP.NET Master Pages Overview

Hopefully, that will give you some direction.

ADFS out the box can only authenticate against AD. If you want a custom authentication mechanism, the classic solution is to create a custom STS e.g. [Identity Server](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/)

Comment: About authentication against AD vs. against other stores, see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313512/can-i-use-adfs-2-0-to-authenticate-certain-users-against-sql-server/4938662#4938662).